# Where clause on childs navigation properties

Tags: linq-to-entities, navigation-properties

i tried to query a table whith a "where clause" base on multiple level child navigation properties.

I have :

- table A whith navigation properties to :

  - Table B whith navigation properties to :

    - Table C

so i try :

```
var query = context.TableA.where(a => a.TableB_navProperties.where(b => b.TbableC_navProperties.where(c => c.prop=="testCondition")));
```

But this query is not correct: visual studio said :
"impossible to convert system.collection.generic.IEnumerable< TableC > to bool"

How can i query table with condition on child of childs navigation properties ?

Thank's

Comment: Just like you would regular nested classes: `context.TableA.where(a => a.TableB_navProperties.TbableC_navProperties.prop=="testCondition")`

Comment: Hi, the navproperties that i want to query are collection of entities so i can't do TableB_navProperties.TbableC_navProperties. is there a way to do nested query on collection IEnumerable<Entity> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. For the navigation properties wich are collection, use Any() instead of where () :

```
var query = context.TableA.where(a => a.TableB_navProperties.Any(b => b.TbableC_navProperties.Any(c => c.prop=="testCondition")));
```

This solution works but the sql generated use a lot of "*Exist subquery*"  so i think it's not very efficient.

Comment: From what I can see, the `EXIST` subquery is the fastest SQL option in most cases.